# Trouble loading the skobbler map

Tags: android, skmaps

I am trying to run the demo project by skobbler, however the app crashes the moment it starts. It runs the SplashActivity.java file which has the code to initialize the map. This is the output from on the run terminal:
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.skobbler.sdkdemo/com.skobbler.sdkdemo.activity.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 20422 on device Pixel_API_25 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.

I am not able to figure out what's causing the app to crash. Is anyone facing similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There use to be some problems running skobbler in emulator. Try on a physical device.

Comment: Oh yes that worked! Thanks! Btw, is there a way of running it on emulator?

Comment: I haven't found a reliable solution other than running on a real device. Some say Genymotion emulator works better for this kind of things.

Comment: Have you worked on skobbler routing and navigation through specific set of points? I am not talking about viapoints, but like a set of points through which i want my route to be calculated between the start and destination point.

Comment: This is a different question and comments are not here to turn into a discussion. If you have more problems you can ask another question. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Android intel emulator supports openGL now

[image]

Here you can choose which GL interface you want to use on your emulator.

[image]

On macOS you can see some information about the openGL running on the emulator. Once you have downloaded the additional tools for xcode.

[image]

[image]

For some more information about emulator hardware acceleration [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html).